# How can we create ringtones in WP7 Mango using mp3 and wma already on the device?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I create a ringtone using existing mp3 and wma files already on the device in WP7 Mango?

Can I use MediaLibrary to get the music files on the device, and then use the ringtone task to create a new ringtone?

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because you don't have access to media streams for the content that is already stored on the phone outside your application. You either must have the files bundled with the application or download them individually from a web server.

Something to consider is written [on my blog](http://dennisdel.com/?p=979).

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this using files on the phone.  What you can do (with Mango), however, is edit files on your computer, ensuring that they are mp3 or WMA format, less than 29 seconds in length, and less than 1 MB in file size, change the Genre to Ringtone, and sync it to your phone through Zune Desktop.  You can then use the file as a ringtone.